# Websphere 8.5.5.16 app server - "Error 404: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found:"

Tags: java, spring-boot, websphere

Websphere 8.5.5.16 app server is behaving weird, sometimes it is working and sometime it is not working,

It is returning '***Error 404: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /publishConfluenceData***' which was working OK and now I didn't do anything new I just re deployed same Springboot generated WAR. I have looked for many places but I didn't get a conclusive root cause, can anyone let me know why Serverlet container is not able to find this path and how to fix this websphere container path finding issue please?.

Small note - contextroot path initialized OK i.e default page launch looks OK,
Additionally Classloader is Parent First is set in Websphere.

Below is the main Springboot class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DmsComponentsTestApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(DmsComponentsTestApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DmsComponentsTestApplication.class, args);
    }

        
    @Controller
    public class DmsComponentsTestController {
        
    @GetMapping("/publishConfluenceData")
    public String publishConfluenceData() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException {
    ---
    ---
    }
    }
}
```

Note: This is working OK on my localhost with embedded tomcat server.

Additional error details :

```
[03/07/20 17:21:42:682 UTC]     FFDC Exception:java.io.FileNotFoundException SourceId:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters -IOE ProbeId:1044
java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /publishConfluenceData
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor._processEDR(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:977)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.processEDR(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:958)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:486)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1114)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4047)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1016)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:213)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1187)
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:694)
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1833)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)

Reporter:null
```

Comment: can any one help me on this issue pls?

Comment: Perhaps it's the same problem as mentioned [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868692/struts-2-and-custom-error-pages-on-websphere-application-server-8-was-8)?